# How can I manually add 4 spaces to code in Stack Overflow answers?

Tags: discussion, design, whitespace

Whenever I paste any code in Stack Overflow by just copying it from [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) and pasting it here in the answer field, it shows that I need to add 4 spaces in every line of code so that it will be formatted as code.

I always manually add 4 spaces in every line of code. Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: This question belongs on the Meta site, not here.  If you are _typing_ out code, pressing SHIFT + ENTER will automatically indent the next line with 4 spaces.  For cutting and pasting, you might have to use some external tool.

Comment: You can also use [Markdown](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks).

Comment: " Is there any solution to this problem?" - Google. Putting "stack overflow code blocks" into google brings you to the page that this question is closed as a duplicate of.

Comment: Workaround: Do it in Visual Studio Code: press *Tab* (the code is already selected), Ctrl + C, Ctrl + Z. (The 'dirty' state of the document is not even affected. And neither is the selection.) It works with the default settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just copy paste the code and simply wrap the code with ```` ``` ```` (three backticks).

like this

```
 //random react code

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function Hello(props) {
  return <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Select all your codes by dragging the mouse, and pressing `ctrl + K`, it will be converted to code block automatically.

or enclose them with  **`** (the symbol above the tab on the keyboard)